# JList selected data from highlighted

Tags: java, swing, listener, jlist

What I am trying to do with a `JList` is be able to select an index by either scrolling with the mouse or using the keyboard up or down buttons without requiring a key press or mouse click event. I have tried looking into listeners and I think that's the right direction to go but if someone could put it simply I would appreciate it so much.

//edit.

To add more detail here is an example of what i mean, see Halo 3 is high lighted but the stock item name etc is for halo 4

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure you can request focus onto the JList and have it select elements without at least one click or keyboard event. Also... "without a key press" is contradictory to "or using a keyboard up or down buttons", yes?

Comment: You can select an item using the up/down arrows on the keypad. You can also scroll the list using the mouse scroll wheel. You should NOT be able to select an item using the scroll wheel. This is not a common UI. If you want to select an item you need to click on it (or use the up/down arrows). That is the standard UI requires the user to use the keyboard or mouse click to select a specify item. Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Users will not know how to use the interface.

Comment: added more detail to my question, im aware its a poorly worded question im trying to explain what i mean better but not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `ListSelectionListener` to the `ListModel` of the `JList`. Then when the selection event is generated you invoke your logic to update the two text fields.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i was looking for but couldnt find